# Autofac TypeLoadException when upgrading MVC 4 -> 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

Trying to upgrade a project from MVC3to MVC5,
the 3->4 part went well and I could run the project.

However, after updating *probably* everything for mvc5, 
I'm getting an exception

> Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'Autofac.Integration.Web.Mvc.AutofacControllerFactory'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

on this row of Application_Start()
`InitContainerProvider();`

the method being called:

```
protected void InitContainerProvider()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            builder.RegisterType<PeriodsProxy>().As<IPeriods>().AsWcfProxy();

            _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
            var factory = new AutofacControllerFactory(_containerProvider);

            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(factory);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
protected void InitContainerProvider()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();

    builder.RegisterType<PeriodsProxy>().As<IPeriods>().AsWcfProxy();

    builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(_containerProvider.ApplicationContainer.BeginLifetimeScope()));
}
```

This example uses the package [**NuGet:** Autofac.Mvc5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc5)

Comment: This is correct. It appears that the old way of registering Autofac for injection in MVC was to set the ControllerFactory. This is now handled using the MVC5 DependencyResolver as dubs has mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me to get on track, however your syntax isnt't quite correct. new constructor signature is AutofacDependencyResolver(ILifetimeScope scope), thus being scope = _containerProvider.ApplicationContainer.BeginLifetimeScope()